# JS-split regex - включить сам разделитель в часть слева

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка, например, "установить ВКЛ/ВЫКЛ".

```
массив_строки = строка.split('/(?=\/)|\s/')
```

в данном случае '/' оказывается в начале следующего элемента - '/ВЫКЛ'

Какой нужен regex для того, что бы появился следующий массив: ['установить', 'ВКЛ/', 'ВЫКЛ'] ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(?=\/)` - положительный блок просмотра вперёд, тогда как тут пригодился бы  блок предварительного просмотра назад, но регулярные выражения JavaScript не поддерживают его. [`(?<=\/)|\s+`](https://regex101.com/r/UtrdWq/2) - так бы оно выглядело в `s.split()`.

Можно найти все совпадения символов, отличных от пробельных и символа косой черты, за которыми может находится 1 необязательный знак косой черты:

```
/[^\s\/]+\/?/g
```

[Демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/UtrdWq/1). Перед `/` обязательно наличие непробельного символа, отличного от `/`.

```js
console.log(
   "установить ВКЛ/ВЫКЛ".match(/[^\s\/]+\/?/g)
);
```

Comment: [`/[^\s\/]*\/|[^\s\/]+(?!\/)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/UtrdWq/3) - если нужно найти отдельно стоящие `/`.

Comment: Спасибо. попробовал console.log('установить ВКЛ/ВЫКЛ'.split('/[^\s\/]+\/?/')) -- но не работает.

Comment: @CodeGust: Повторю: **`.match(/[^\s\/]+\/?/g)`**. Используйте **`String#match()`**. `String#split()` не будет работать, не в сегодняшней версии JavaScript.

Comment: Точно, с match работает, спасиБо!